# Можно ли использовать в нескольких функциях одинаковые имена для переменных?

Tags: kotlin

Есть две функции(Android Studio), в них одинаковые наименование переменных:

```
val message = ..
```

Это не будет считаться грубой ошибкой?

И вообще можно использовать в нескольких функциях имена одних и тех же переменных?

```
 fun toastMe2(view: View) {
    val message = Toast.makeText(this, "Как ты2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    message.show()
}

fun toastMe3(view: View) {
    val message = Toast.makeText(this, "Опа3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    message.show()
}
```

Comment: Не будет. Можно.

Comment: Ошибкой тут можно считать разве что создание двух почти идентичных функций для вывода двух разных строк, когда можно написать одну функцию, а выводимую строку можно передавать через параметр. Но это не грубая ошибка (пока у вас только 2 таких функций, а не 100).

Comment: Cпасибо, а не могли бы вы пожалуйста дать мне пример одной функции, которая может выводить два разных сообщения.

Comment: @Человек `fun showToast(message: String) = Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно можно! Области видимости же разные.
К примеру, подавляющее большинство имен переменных в счетчиках - это просто `i`.

Навскидку, основные требования к переменным - описательное имя, избегание зарезервированных и около-ключевых слов, читаемость, отсутствие перекрытия, и т.д.